# link from my android app to a page in instagram app

Tags: android, instagram

how can I make a link from my android app to a page in Instagram app ?? 
for example for facebook I use below code :

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

   try {
    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/5676133521"));
   } catch (Exception e) {
    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://touch.facebook.com/androiddevs"));
   }
}
```

}